# How to add a "unit only" item to "New" menu/object repository in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, wizard

I've seen numerous examples of how to add a form wizard to the Delphi Object Repository (for instance, in the TeeChart source), but I want to add the equivalent of the "New Unit" but just with content that I generate.  In other words, I can't figure out how to JUST create a unit without creating a form with it.  I am currently trying to do this via OTA in Delphi XE via the IOTAModuleCreator, but it wants a form ancestor.  Is there a different interface I should use, is there someplace I can just pass a nil to avoid the form, or is this not even something that can be done?

Comment: You mean something like a new DUnitX TestCase ... https://github.com/VSoftTechnologies/DUnitX/blob/f-d10-seattle/Expert/DUnitX.Expert.NewUnitWizard.pas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per what Sir Rufo said, this indeed did exactly as I was looking for:

https://github.com/VSoftTechnologies/DUnitX/blob/f-d10-seattle/Expert/DUnitX.Expert.NewUnitWizard.pas

Comment: Rather than just post a link, it's more useful to summarize the actual answer to your question here, and then add the link as an additional reference. If the link disappears (is moved, changed, etc.) in the future, your answer loses all value to future readers, which is specifically why link-only answers are strongly discouraged here.